# Vite Vanilla build with Tailwind doesn't work

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, vite

I created a vanilla js project with Vite and installed Tailwind as the docs says. When I run in dev mode the classes works, but when I build the dist folder and serve that build it doesn't.

My postcss.config.js is this

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

And my tailwind config is this

```
module.exports = {
  purge: [
    './src/**/*.html',
    './src/**/*.js',
  ],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can follow these steps to resolve the issue:

1. Remove the code from your **main.js** file (part of Vite's template).
2. You may also want to remove the `#app` block from the **styles.css** (part of Vite's template).
3. Add the following line to your **index.html**:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
   ```
4. Now in the `<body>`, you can use Tailwind like this:

   ```
   <div class="text-2xl">Hello, World!</div>
   ```

PS: thanks to [this video](https://youtu.be/41kqZYK3wRI?t=371) (from 6:11 to 7:36) for the solution.